# How to properly build a JSON that contains a property named * (asterisk)

Tags: java, json

While trying to do some calls against elasticSearch's API (using Java), I faced an issue. One property in the big JSON that is sent, is just an asterisk.

```
 "fields":{  
         "*":{  
            "highlight_query":{    
              ...}  }  }
```

My initial way of working was to use a model class that would be mapped to the model to be sent, but it's obvious that the asterisk blocks this way of working - you can't have variables named *

The alternative that I took into consideration is to paste the whole JSON in a string.Format and give parameters, but this would lead to a String.Format with lots of parameters which is totally ugly.

Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Jackson to convert the model class to json, you can tell it what name to give a field by using the `@JsonProperty` annotation.

```
public class MyModelClass {
    public String foo;

    @JsonProperty("*") // what you want the property to be named
    public String bar; 
}
```

This will give a json on the format of

```
{
  "foo": "someValue",
  "*": "someOtherValue"
}
```

Comment: this perfectly answers my question and works like a charm. Thank you very much Matsemann!